# How to setup local network repository on Windows using Apache24 (Win environment) with WSL

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Apache24 to host a local network repository (APT Url: `http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080`), and by generating the `Packages.bz2` using `dpkg-scanpackages` on WSL (Ubuntu). However, generated Packages file will be using the WSL file path (`/mnt/c/somefolder/debs/debsfile.deb`), and this makes package manager can't find the file when trying to install any package.

Manually modify the Packages file and replace every Filename with `C:\somefolder\debs` return 
`Method http has died unexpectedly!` and 
`Sub-process http received signal 5`error.

What's the appropriate way to generate the `Packages.bz2` in this environment combo? What's the correct setup to achieve this in such environment combo? This is the bash script I used to create it:

```
cd /mnt/c/Apache24/htdocs
rm -f Packages.bz2
dpkg-scanpackages -m /mnt/c/somefolder/debs > Packages
bzip2 Packages
```

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://www.maketecheasier.com/setup-local-repository-ubuntu/) website for set it up on actual linux. Win+WSL combo however is very lacking on resources, in fact when you search for `local network repository WSL`, this post is the first result on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I solved this. You'll have to put the debs file a folder same as the Apache server, such as:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\debs
```

and modify the Filename in Packages relative to the server, such as

```
Filename: ./debs/somedeb.deb
```

This can be done in one go using bash script:

```
cd /mnt/c/Apache24/htdocs
rm -f Packages.bz2
dpkg-scanpackages -m /mnt/c/Apache24/htdocs/debs > Packages
while read a; do
    echo ${a//debs/./debs}
done < Packages > Packages_
rm -f Packages
mv Packages_ Packages
bzip2 Packages
```